I imported an object from Roblox Studio but when it gets imported to blender its invisible and when it is selected there is an outline
I am new to blender, and I don't really know how to fix this. I was animating and then the next second it was invisible. I'm guessing I pressed a button but I'm not sure which one. I would like a lot of help with this as it doesn't allow me to get any work done.
enter image description here
I have not tried much but resetting the settings to factory default with no luck.
